# How do I reference/cite a figure created specially for me by someone else?

Tags: citations, thesis, citation-style, latex

A friend of mine helped to created figures shown in my thesis. I know that you do not need te reference figures created yourself. (How) am I supposed to give credits to my friend?

Is there a special Latex record or field?

Comment: Are you specifically focused on citation style only or do you want more general advice on how to acknowledge the figures you use?

Comment: Generally this goes in an acknowledgments section, unless the figure warrants coauthorship.

Comment: All figures from official sources (papers, webpages, books, articles) are correctly referrences. I only wanted advice with regard to creditting my friend for creating the figures. I think the acknowledgement section will suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are the usual LaTex characters for registered trademark and copyright though I doubt if your friend will press for these. It would be unseemly I feel if you were to put ref numbers on each or any of these figures with a footnote on the page end; or even to make a reference comment at the end of the thesis. However I've seen trademark symbols in engineering theses where a branded material was being evaluated - in fact they were *everywhere* that material was mentioned !

In every research publication there is a space for Acknowledgements. Journal publications have it towards the end, theses have it before Chapter 1. In this section you pay tribute to many named and/or unnamed colleagues and friends for practical assistance and helpful discussions. Explicit mention of the party providing the set of figures in question would be best placed here. If the person normally provides such figures on a professional basis, e.g. a graphic content designer in private practice, you may mention the business name but not perhaps any web site address. If the person is a university employee, e.g. someone working in the university printing press, you may mention their bureau. For example,

***Acknowledgements***

*" ... and a special thanks to John Smythe of Magraphix for design work on figures 3.m - 3.w . . ."*

or

*" ... and a special thanks to Soraya Helegloglu at Trinity College London Press for design work on figures 3.m - 3.w . . ."*

Comment: "theses have it before Chapter 1" - That's one out of two possibilities.

Comment: You've seen it *after* the end of the thesis proper ?

Comment: Sure.  I'd even consider it the normal option in the theses I've seen.

Comment: I saw one engineering thesis with an acknowledgements section immediately after the conclusions and suggestions for further work sections. It was quite long read like he'd got a helluva lot of help from everyone on everything. Almost like the acknowledgements at the end of a mojor political biography.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: I just checked a bunch of theses and it might well be a regional thing.

Comment: Yes. Looked at PhD LaTex templates offered by various universities in UK and Ireland, they are much the same. Even Harvard/Princeton/NYU's one https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv is sort of similar. Slight variations of some "official" LaTex template put together in 1970s. But I know good theses that were not so orthodox in their format. So in the end, where to put the Acknowledgements (or Dedication) comes down to where the author wants them. It's the main content that counts.

Comment: To be fair, it's the acknowledgements which everyone reads first, so it makes sense to put them at the beginning ;)

Comment: Yes, Mr Contradiction.

Comment: I didn't say it made sense to put them at the end. I said there are places where it is customary to put it at the end. Indeed, if you put it at the end, people at least have to flip once through your thesis before they get to read it!

Comment: Actually, I'm one of those who *do* read things like **Dedication** and **Acknowledgements** first. Carefully read, it can give an insight to the character of the author and his/her approach to the topic. For example, after finding a recentish (80s) thesis covering a topic of interest, I read the Deds after the Abstract. It was too touching to be false: his parents (like they all do), siblings, a couple and another man from his home town; then In Memoriam of his dead brother and the now deceased wife of forementioned man from his home town. Any guy honoring teachers and neighbors can't be bad.